# wxpython postevent from coroutine to a parent window (modal)

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, python-asyncio

I got a coroutine running to catch events sent by a footswitch device. This coroutine is launched from the main window as following.

```
class FootswitchMonitor(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title,
                         size=(350, 150))
        self.InitUI()
        StartCoroutine(self.footswitch_callback, self)
        self.Bind(EVT_FOOTSWITCH, self.pedal)

    def on_footswitch(self, evt):
        print(f"eid: {evt.GetId()} code: {evt.code} ")

    async def footswitch_callback(self):
        device = get_footswitch_device()
        device.grab()
        key_pressed = None
        async for ev in device.async_read_loop():
            if ev.type == 1 and ev.value == 1: # only key events and key_down
                if key_pressed != ev.code:
                    event = footswitch_event(code=ev.code)
                    wx.PostEvent(self, event)
                    key_pressed = ev.code
            else:
                key_pressed = None

    def setup_footswitch(self, event):
        cDialog = ConfigDialog(None)
        cDialog.ShowModal()
        cDialog.Destroy()
```

In order to setup the device I use a `ConfigDialog` dialog box where I'd like to bind the same `EVT_FOOTSWITCH`.

```
class ConfigDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize(350, 450)
        self.SetTitle("Configuration")
        self.Bind(EVT_FOOTSWITCH, self.footswitch_setup_callback)
```

And this is where it hurts. The main coroutine has `FootswitchMonitor` frame as target: wx.PostEvent(**self**, event). So the ConfigDialog windows won't get it.

I cannot run another coroutine with this device in the parent windows because it is grabed, which is locked by the main coroutine.

So my question is how can I catch the EVT_FOOTSWITCH in `ConfigDialog` a parent windows. Is it possible to post the event globaly? Is it possible to stop the main coroutine to run anotheone in the modal window?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar where I run reading the footpedal in a separate thread.
If the user wishes to reconfigure the pedal settings, I simply stop the thread, for the duration of the reconfiguration, then restart it.
Stopping the thread also `ungrabs` the device.
I do insist the program is restarted, as I only read the configuration of the footpedal's settings at program start. I found it less complicated this way.

Your other option, if you wish to attack it from a different angle, is to `Unbind` the event i.e. `self.Unbind(EVT_FOOTSWITCH)` and `ungrab` the device.
Then `Bind` it to your reconfiguration routine, which `Unbind`'s when it finishes and finally rebind the event back to the original, whilst `regrabbing` the device, when you return to the main app.

My rather vast code can be perused at https://sourceforge.net/projects/footswitch2 , if you need further clues.
When browsing the file fs2.py search for `PedalThread`

Comment: I'm impressed, you did an incredible work! Just to say, why didn't you use wxasync and async instead of thread? It's maybe easier to stop the thread in your case. I gonna dig deeper in your code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EmilioConte Development started using python 2.6, before wxasync or indeed async. Back then threading was the solution of choice and as it works, I've never felt the need to re-code it. Given that the minimum time slot I have to deal with is a humans reaction time 1/10 of second, it's always been sufficient.